# Failed authentication

Tags: active-directory, authentication, openldap, kerberos, sssd

I am newbie in this world and I need help.
For the past weeks I have been trying to find the answer to my problem, but withour success.
I am trying to authenticate my CentOS machine against Active Directory (on my Windows Server 2012 machine) via LDAP and Kerberos. I used authconfig-tui and select: User information-Use LDAP and Authentication: Use Kerberos.

LDAP Settings:

```
Server: ldap://10.0.2.15 (my server IP)
Base DN: dc=example,dc=local
```

Kerberos settings:

```
Realm: EXAMPLE.LOCAL
KDC: 10.0.2.15
Admin Server: SERVER.EXAMPLE.LOCAL
```

As I learned, this configuration is not enough so I edited my *sssd.conf* file:

```
*autofs_provider = ldap    
cache_credentials = True    
krb5_kpasswd = SERVER.EXAMPLE.LOCAL    
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=local    
krb5_server = 10.0.2.15   
id_provider = ldap    
auth_provider = krb5    
chpass_provider = krb5    
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True    
ldap_uri = ldap://10.0.2.15    
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.LOCAL    
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False    
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts

[sssd]    
domains = default, example.local  
config_file_version = 2 
services = nss, pam, autofs

[domain/example.local]    
ad_domain = example.local    
id_provider = ad    
autofs_provider = ldap    
cache_credentials = True    
krb5_kpasswd = SERVER.EXMAPLE.LOCAL   
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=local    
krb5_server = 10.0.2.15   
id_provider = ldap    
auth_provider = krb5    
chpass_provider = krb5   
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True   
ldap_uri = ldap://10.0.2.15    
krb5_realm = EXMAPLE.LOCAL    
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False    
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

I restated the service. Then I tried to

```
su - exampleuser@example.local
```

And it worked. But it I try to `kinit` or `klist` I receive this error:

> kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'EXAMPLE.LOCAL' while getting initial credentials

I also have another error when trying to http://localhost via Apache. My error_log file says:

> LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed. Can´t contact LDAP server

Am I doing something wrong?
Any help would be useful.
Thanks in advance.

If you need more information just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the following key/values:

```
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
ad_server = server.example.local
```

Comment: I tried that. Same error appear.

Comment: Are you sudo'ing kinit/klist with an authorised AD account?
You can specify the user with: kinit -U ad_super_user[@example.local]